# React inline styling changes once I wrap number in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm building a React table component with rows and columns. Naturally, I want the rows to be distributed vertically and the numbers within the rows to be distributed horizontally.

Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

But when I wrap each number in a simple `Cell` component, I end up with this:

[image]

React Code:

```
function Cell({ number }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {number}
        </div>
    )
}

function Row({ row }) {
    // problem when data point is wrapped in Cell
    const mapped = row.map((datapoint, index) => {
        return <li className="horizontalList" key={index.toString()}><Cell number={datapoint}/></li>
    })
    
    // uncomment this and comment out the other one to see how it should look
    
    // const mapped = row.map((datapoint, index) => {
    //     return <li className="horizontalList" key={index.toString()}>{datapoint}</li>
    // })
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <ul>
                {mapped}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}


function App() {
   const data = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ]

  const mapped = data.map((row, index) => {
      return <li className="verticalList" key={index.toString()}><Row row={row}/></li>
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
            <ul>
                {mapped}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.horizontalList {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}

.verticalList {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I recommend turning it into a snippet

Comment: Yes, a snippet of the output HTML would be super helpful :)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Oh I get it. A snippet attached to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements (e.g. `<span>`) normally display *inline* beside eaah other. However, when you insert a block element (e.g. `<div>`) inside like:

```html
<span>
  <div></div>
</span>
```

That `div` keeps taking the full width and ignores the boundaries of its parent `span`.
And that's exactly what happens when you wrap the number, which is inline by your styles, inside a `<Cell />`, as it's just a `div`.

Run this code snippet to check the difference:

```html
<h4>Inline elements</h4>

<span>item</span>
<span>item</span>

<hr />

<h4>Block element inside inline elements</h4>

<span><div>item</div></span>
<span><div>item</div></span>
```

**Solution:**
Make the `<Cell />` a `span` instead of `div`.